# How can I send data to docker?

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

I have the following problem. I want to send data continuing to the smart contract (chaincode) using Hyperledger Fabric. The data are temperature values measured by different pi's. They send the measured data to the chaincode. The problem I'm facing is the fact that the pi's are sending data continuing, means they send it like every second to the chaincode. 
The temperature sensors use local binaries, which are not part of the docker repository. My solution is to send local data to the docker network. But I have no idea how.
Does anyone have a better solution or just know how to send local data to the docker network? I would appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

whenever i invoke chaincode from the cli i use `docker exec -it <container name> bash`

an example being

```
docker exec -it cli peer chaincode invoke -o orderer2.example.com:7050 -n mycc -c '{"Args":["set", "a", "20"]}' -C mychannel
```